# Django ValueError at /updatestudent/3 Cannot assign "'1'": "Student.class_id" must be a "Class" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

ValueError at /updatestudent/3 Cannot assign "'1'": "Student.class_id" must be a "Class" instance. This error comes when I am trying to update my student model. when I am updating username also than it doesn't throw any error but if I am not updating username than only this throwing this error

Any help is appericiated.

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1,'HOD'),(2,'Staff'),(3,'Student'))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(default=1, choices=gender_type, max_length=10)
    profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='student/profile-images/%y/%m/%d/', default='student/profile-images/default.jpg', blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.TextField()
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    def full_name(self):
        return self.admin.first_name+' '+self.admin.last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.admin.username

class Session(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    session_start= models.IntegerField()
    session_end = models.IntegerField()
    objects = models.Manager()
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.session_start} {self.session_end}'

class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Class(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.CharField(default='CSE', choices=branch_data, max_length=40)
    year = models.CharField(default='First Year', choices=year_data, max_length=15)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.course} {self.branch} {self.year} {self.session}'

    def name(self):
        return f'{self.course} {self.branch} {self.year} {self.session}'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from django.db.models import fields
from .models import (AdminHOD, Staff, Student, Class,  
                    CustomUser, Course, Session, Attendance, 
                    ExamType, Exam, Subject)
from .models import branch_data, year_data


gchoice = (('1','Male'),('2','Female'))
sesschoice = tuple((i.id, i.id) for i in Session.objects.all())
courchoice = tuple((i.id,i) for i in Course.objects.all())
choice_exam = tuple((i.id,i.name) for i in ExamType.objects.all())
all_class = tuple((i.id, i.name) for i in Class.objects.all())

class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']

class StudentUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=gchoice)
    address = forms.CharField()
    class_id = forms.ChoiceField(choices=all_class)

    class Meta: 
        model = Student
        fields = ['gender', 'class_id', 'address']
```

views.py

```
    if request.method=='POST':
        uform = UserUpdateForm(request.POST)
        sform = StudentUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if uform.is_valid():
            address = request.POST.get('address')
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            clas = Class.objects.get(id=request.POST['class_id'])
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            gender = request.POST.get('gender')
            print(clas)
            try:
                student = Student.objects.get(id=id)
                user = student.admin
                user.username = username
                user.email = email
                user.save()
                student.address = address
                student.gender = str(gender)
                student.class_id = clas
                student.updated_at = datetime.datetime.now()
                student.save()
                messages.success(request,'Student successfully Updated.')
                return redirect('/managestudent')
            except:
                messages.error(request,'Student has not been Updated due to some technical issues.')
                return render(request, 'cmsapp/hod/studentupdate.html', {'uform':uform,'sform':sform})
        else:
            messages.error(request,sform.errors)
            return render(request, 'cmsapp/hod/studentupdate.html', {'uform':uform,'sform':sform})

    else:
        uform = UserUpdateForm(instance=Student.objects.get(id=id).admin)
        sform = StudentUpdateForm(instance=Student.objects.get(id=Student.objects.get(id=id).id))
        return render(request, 'cmsapp/hod/studentupdate.html', {'uform':uform,'sform':sform})
```

studentupdate.html

```
        <h3>Update Student</h3>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{uform}}
            {{sform}}
            <button type="submit">Update Student</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\CollegeErp\cmsapp\hodviews.py", line 176, in update_student
    messages.error(request,sform.errors)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 376, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 400, in _post_clean
    self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 63, in construct_instance
    f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 891, in save_form_data
    setattr(instance, self.name, data)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Deep Saingar\Desktop\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /updatestudent/3
Exception Value: Cannot assign "'1'": "Student.class_id" must be a "Class" instance.
```

Comment: If possible can you share the whole traceback

Comment: just added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In `StudentUpdateForm`, try to change the `class_id` field to:

```
class_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Class.objects.all())
```

Comment: For Now it is working but now I am getting a different type of issue, when I am changing username all is working fine but when I am not changing username the page doesn't go to managestudent it remain on studentupdate.

Comment: From your code, it seems it can happen on multiple places. You also have a bare except, so it could possibly be going there. Try to debug and see if there are any `form.is_valid` calls which give you false, or if any exceptions are raised within the `try` block.

Comment: there is error which come from form.errors which says a user with that username is already exists, if I dont change the username. And if I change the username than it don't throw that error.

Comment: Is there any way to change the user without the requirement of changing the username.

Comment: Then it means it's caused by not passing an instance in your `UserUpdateForm`. It thinks you are trying to create a new user, but your usernames are unique

Comment: I think it should be another question, as that new problem is a little tricky to fix

Comment: This comment for appreciation, for clearing this thing, Now it is working fine.